# JavaFX: automatically expand ChoiceBox when on focus

Tags: javafx-8

I have a `ChoiceBox` for which I want to show the dropdown menu if it has gained focus when cycling though the input controls (focus traversal). I.e. I don't want the user to press SPACE first as he must make a choice anyway. I have the following code so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        ChoiceBox<String> box1 = new ChoiceBox<String>();
        box1.getItems().addAll("1", "2", "3");
        ChoiceBox<String> box2 = new ChoiceBox<String>();
        box2.getItems().addAll("a", "b", "c");

        for (ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox : Arrays.asList(box1, box2)) {
            choiceBox.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue && !oldValue) {
                    // transition from unfocused to focused -> expand choicebox
                    if (!choiceBox.isShowing()) {
                        choiceBox.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        pane.add(box1, 0, 0);
        pane.add(box2, 1, 0);
        root.getChildren().add(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This code works fine when I use the keyboard for focus traversal, but if I click the the (unfocused) `ChoiceBox` with the mouse, the dropdown shows for a few miliseconds and then hides instantly again. I guess that the `ChoiceBox` has a predefined `EventHandler` for mouse events which "toggles" whether the items are shown or not. Apparently, the `FocusedProperty` is changing first, showing the items, and then the `MouseEvents` hides them again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: why do I get a downvote for this question?

Comment: ok, I added SSCCE, see edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [consume](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--) method of MouseEvents to stop further propagation of the Event through the dispatch chain.

```
  final ChangeListener<? super Boolean> showHideBox = ( __, ___, isFocused ) ->
  {
    if ( isFocused.booleanValue() )
    {
      choiceBox.show();
    }
    else
    {
      choiceBox.hide();
    }
  };
  choiceBox.focusedProperty().addListener( showHideBox );
  choiceBox.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, release ->
  {
    release.consume();
    choiceBox.requestFocus();
  } );
```

Full example : https://gist.github.com/flasheater/0cc365227a235c3fb794 .

Comment: thats great! I came up with a similar solution in the meantime, but yours is way cleaner

Comment: I realized that your solution is not fully working, namely when the choiceBox is already focused (and not showing). In this case, the ChangeListener is not firing, and thus its impossible to expand it with the mouse. But its easy to add the corresponding logic to the eventFilter (MOUSE_RELEASED)

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working for your case. What exactly do you mean with "not showing"? visible = false? I'd be interested in observing this behavior.

Comment: with "not showing" I mean not expanding the dropdown menu. You can observe this behavior with my sample app (extended by your code): hide the dropdown by pressing SPACE, then try to open it again with the Mouse -> its not working